# ImportError: libc10.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, pytorch

While running smdataparallel, I see following error

```
# python
Python 3.6.10 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, May  8 2020, 02:54:21)
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import smdistributed.dataparallel.torch.distributed as dist
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/smdistributed/dataparallel/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    import smddpcommon as hc
ImportError: libc10.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What is smdataparallel? ;)

Comment: Glad you asked: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/data-parallel-use-api.html

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`libc10.so` is made available by pytorch. Hence first

```
import torch
```

and then import packages that depend on pytorch.

Comment: is this dependent on the torch version?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` to locate this file. For example, `find YOUR_HOME_PATH -name "*libc10.so*"`. For example, I found `/MY_HOME_PATH/anaconda3/envs/xrnerf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/lib/libc10.so` in mine.